# How to manage sub-domains on winhost with URL Rewrite and ASP.NET Optimization's bundles

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, url-rewriting, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-optimization

I am using ASP.NET MVC4 with WinHost.

Just like the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678528/how-to-manage-sub-domains-on-winhost-with-iis7-url-rewrite-2-0), I ran into the same issue:

> I'm trying out WinHost and I'm running into some issues with
>   sub-domains. On WinHost, you can have multiple sub-domains per hosting
>   account, but each sub-domain points to the root website. E.g. you can
>   have www.example.com, sub1.example.com, and sub2.example.com but all
>   of them display the content at http://www.example.com/.
>
> Other Hosts allow you to point sub-domains to a sub folder in your
>   website. This would allow you to point sub1.example.com to /sub1,
>   sub2.example.com to /sub2 and www.example.com to /.
>
> WinHost recommends using an asp/aspx page to redirect
>   http://sub1.example.com to http://sub1.example.com/sub1, which points
>   to /sub1. While that would work, I'd like to not have the subdomain in
>   the url twice.
>
> So I tried using IIS7 URL Rewrite to point http://sub1.example.com to
>   /sub1. Ben Powell describes this in detail on [his blog](http://blog.benpowell.co.uk/2010/02/winhostcom-how-to-really-run-multiple.html).

I've managed to get this portion to work so that http://sub1.example.com actually points to my virtual application "/sub1" in IIS.

If I use Url.Content, it works flawlessly.

Now, I am using ASP.NET Optimization and I bundle scripts and css. Issue is that it absolutely require a relative url ie:

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

However, because it's a relative url here is what I will get in the markup:

```
<script src="/sub1/bundles/jqueryval?v=UgyEMAYOuSB9Bb6HcOEVHpd6fIIp54yF086SRNVcdIY1"></script>
```

Of course, because of the "sub1" it doesn't find the file. I thought about URL Redirect that I never actually got to work. Maybe a route in MVC? Unsure how to do this as well. I could also drop the bundling alltogether to use "Url.Content" which I think is sad.

What would be the best way to handle this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I know you can use IBundleTransform to modify contents in a bundle based on unique circumstances. You may be able to modify the bundle context itself. Here is a link [MVC4 StyleBundle not resolving images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355935/mvc4-stylebundle-not-resolving-images)

Comment: My issue is really regarding the "Script.Render(...)" function which renders the virtual directory.

Comment: You said that you have configured some rewrite rules in iis. I wonder if it would be possible to catch your routing issue also in startup code using RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)?